# Can I bring warming pads on the plane?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, airport-security, hand-luggage

I am going to visit Lapland soon, and coming from the warm climate of Israel, I am sure to feel the cold.

In addition to buying a good coat and other gear, I also bought warming pads. Specifically, http://body-warmer.com/ where it says that it is "*Made from wood and iron powder, Non-poisonous, not flammable*".

But I'm not sure if these would be possibly to bring on the plane with me. Especially since I usually try avoid checking my bags, and pack very lightly so I can take everything with me as a carry-on.

(If it matters, I will be flying with both Ukraine Airlines and Finnair.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TSA allows [these](https://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/hazmat_safety/) so it is very unlikely either Finnair or Ukraine International Airlines will not.

[image: body warmer]

However 'marginal' decisions rest with the specific airlines and you may have to contact each to be *certain* - because they tend to list (a) only some of what is banned and maybe (b) 'typical' items that are not, so anything mildly exotic may not feature in either list.

Comment: (If no other answer specific to my situation comes up in the next couple of days, I'll accept this answer.)